# Deploying django in a virtualenv with help of apache/mod_wsgi daemon mode

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have spent lot of time googling and reading documentation and stackoverflow answers, but  couldn't be able to deploy django in a virtualenv with help of apache/mod_wsgi daemon mode.

Here is My apache conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin admin@example.com
 ServerName example.com
 LogLevel info
 WSGIDaemonProcess example.com python-path=/var/www/testproject:/root/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages
 WSGIProcessGroup example.com
 WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/testproject/testproject/wsgi.py
   <Directory /var/www/testproject/testproject>
     <Files wsgi.py>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Files>
   </Directory>
   ErrorLog /var/www/testproject/log/error.log
   CustomLog /var/www/testproject/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

This is my wsgi.py fil. ( I haven't touch it):

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "testproject.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Here my log file:

```
[Thu Jan 22 18:45:12.289458 2015] [:info] [pid 585:tid 139777547847552] mod_wsgi (pid=585): Cleanup interpreter ''.
[Thu Jan 22 18:45:12.293845 2015] [:info] [pid 585:tid 139777547847552] mod_wsgi (pid=585): Terminating Python.
[Thu Jan 22 18:45:12.296594 2015] [:info] [pid 585:tid 139777547847552] mod_wsgi (pid=585): Python has shutdown.
[Thu Jan 22 18:45:13.364017 2015] [:info] [pid 982:tid 139775604578176] mod_wsgi (pid=982): Attach interpreter ''.
[Thu Jan 22 18:45:13.365960 2015] [:info] [pid 982:tid 139775604578176] mod_wsgi (pid=982): Adding '/var/www/testproject' to path.
[Thu Jan 22 18:45:13.366464 2015] [:info] [pid 982:tid 139775604578176] mod_wsgi (pid=982): Adding '/root/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages' to path.
[Thu Jan 22 18:45:35.255450 2015] [:info] [pid 982:tid 139775484114688] mod_wsgi (pid=982): Create interpreter 'example.com|'.
[Thu Jan 22 18:45:35.257781 2015] [:info] [pid 982:tid 139775484114688] mod_wsgi (pid=982): Adding '/var/www/testproject' to path.
[Thu Jan 22 18:45:35.258663 2015] [:info] [pid 982:tid 139775484114688] mod_wsgi (pid=982): Adding '/root/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages' to path.
[Thu Jan 22 18:45:35.259379 2015] [:info] [pid 982:tid 139775484114688] [remote 206.190.152.176:8971] mod_wsgi (pid=982, process='env1', application='example.com|'): Loading WSGI script '/var/www/testproject/testproject/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Jan 22 18:45:35.259995 2015] [:error] [pid 982:tid 139775484114688] [remote 206.190.152.176:8971] mod_wsgi (pid=982): Target WSGI script '/var/www/testproject/testproject/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Thu Jan 22 18:45:35.260417 2015] [:error] [pid 982:tid 139775484114688] [remote 206.190.152.176:8971] mod_wsgi (pid=982): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/testproject/testproject/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Jan 22 18:45:35.260669 2015] [:error] [pid 982:tid 139775484114688] [remote 206.190.152.176:8971] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Jan 22 18:45:35.260888 2015] [:error] [pid 982:tid 139775484114688] [remote 206.190.152.176:8971]   File "/var/www/testproject/testproject/wsgi.py", line 13, in <module>
[Thu Jan 22 18:45:35.261212 2015] [:error] [pid 982:tid 139775484114688] [remote 206.190.152.176:8971]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Thu Jan 22 18:45:35.261463 2015] [:error] [pid 982:tid 139775484114688] [remote 206.190.152.176:8971] ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
[Thu Jan 22 18:45:35.693482 2015] [:info] [pid 982:tid 139775500916480] [remote 206.190.152.176:37373] mod_wsgi (pid=982, process='env1', application='example.com|'): Loading WSGI script '/var/www/testproject/testproject/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Jan 22 18:45:35.694122 2015] [:error] [pid 982:tid 139775500916480] [remote 206.190.152.176:37373] mod_wsgi (pid=982): Target WSGI script '/var/www/testproject/testproject/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Thu Jan 22 18:45:35.694140 2015] [:error] [pid 982:tid 139775500916480] [remote 206.190.152.176:37373] mod_wsgi (pid=982): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/testproject/testproject/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Jan 22 18:45:35.694180 2015] [:error] [pid 982:tid 139775500916480] [remote 206.190.152.176:37373] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Jan 22 18:45:35.694220 2015] [:error] [pid 982:tid 139775500916480] [remote 206.190.152.176:37373]   File "/var/www/testproject/testproject/wsgi.py", line 13, in <module>
[Thu Jan 22 18:45:35.694267 2015] [:error] [pid 982:tid 139775500916480] [remote 206.190.152.176:37373]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Thu Jan 22 18:45:35.694296 2015] [:error] [pid 982:tid 139775500916480] [remote 206.190.152.176:37373] ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
```

`example.com` is my domain name and 
`env1` is the name of my virtualenv

In my log file I can see that virtualenv  has been added to the path:

```
'/root/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python2.7/site-packages' to path.
```

But still I am getting error:

```
ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
```

Installing django globally solve the issue, but I that's not what I want.

I am on `Ubuntu 12.10`, `Django 1.7`, `Python 2.7`

references:

1. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#using-mod-wsgi-daemon-mode
2. https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide#Delegation_To_Daemon_Process
3. http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/why-are-you-using-embedded-mode-of.html

Comment: Finally I succeeded in setting up django:

Adopting Hit and Trial approach, I did following things:
1. created on new user, added it to su group

2. Installed virtualenwrapper by logging as user

3. Changed root's venv path  to user's venv path

3.was executing `source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` on every reboot to make `workon` work. as I am on a VPS, reboot is not so frequent, so I never bother about putting it in  `~/.bashrc` .  I had nothing to do so I put this line in '~/.bashrc'

4. Restarted server and Voila! It worked

I guess my  #3 action did it but  I am not sure

Comment: I recommend that you add an answer describing in more detail what exactly you did. Btw, to enable a virtualenv on reboot invalidates the whole idea of virtualenv anyway...